# Optimize dataset for floating point add/sub/mul/div

Tags: math, floating-point, precision

Suppose we have a data set of numbers, with which we want to do some calculations using addition/subtraction/multiplication/division using a computer.

The coverage of the real numbers by the floating point representation varies a lot, depending on the number being represented:

In terms of absolute precision in the real->FP mapping the "holes" grow towards the bigger numbers, with a weird hole around 0, depending on the architecture. Due to this, the add/sub precision towards the bigger numbers will drop.

If we divide 2 consecutive numbers which are represented in our floating point representation, the result of the division will be bigger both while going to the bigger numbers and when going to smaller and smaller fractions.

**So, my question is:**

Is there a "sweet interval" for floats on an ordinary PC today, where the results for the arithmetics with the said operators (add/sub/mul/div) are just more precise?

If I have a data set of many-significant-digit numbers like `"123123123123123"`, `"134534513412351151"`, etc., with which I want to do some arithmetics, which floating point interval should it be converted to, to have the best precision for the result?

- Since floating points are something like `1.xxx*10^yyy`, `2.xxx*10^yyy`, ..., `9.xxx*10^yyy`, I would assume, converting my numbers into the [1, 9] interval would give the best results for the memory consumed, but I may be terribly wrong...

Suppose I use C, can such conversion even be made? Is there a best-practice to do that? Before an operation, C will convert the operands to the same format, so I guess I would have to use a string representation, inject a "." somewhere and parse that as float.

**Please note:**

This is a theoretical question, I don't have an actual data set on my hand that would decide what is best. On the same note, the mentioning of C was random, I am also interested in responses like "forget C, I would use this and this, BECAUSE it supports this and this".

Please spare me from answers like "this cannot be answered, because it depends on the actual operations, since the results may be in another magnitude range than the original data, etc., etc.". Let's suppose that the results of the calculation is more or less in the same interval, as the operands. Sure, when dividing the "more-or-less the same magnitude" operands, the result will be somewhere between 1-10, maybe 0.1-100, ... , but that is probably exactly the best interval they can be in.

Of course, if the answer includes some explanation, other than a brush-off, I will be happy to read it!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The absolute precision of floating-point numbers changes with the magnitude of the numbers because the exponent changes. The relative precision does not change, except for numbers near the bottom of the exponent range, where underflow occurs. If you multiply binary floating-point numbers by a power of two, perform arithmetic (suitably adjusted for the scaling), and reverse the scaling, the results will be identical to doing the arithmetic without scaling, barring effects from overflow and underflow. If your arithmetic does involve underflow or overflow, then scaling could help avoid that. For example, if your precision is suffering because your numbers are so small that some intermediate results are below the normal range of the floating-point format, then scaling by a power of two can avoid the loss of precision from underflow.

If you scale by something other than a power of two, the results can be different, due to changes in the significands. The effects will generally be tiny, and whether the results are better or worse will effectively be random chance, except in carefully engineered special situations.

Comment: Nitpick: relative precision is reduced for values small enough that they cannot be stored as normalized floating-point numbers but need to be stored as subnormal (a.k.a. "denormal") floating-point numbers. Arguably this falls under "effects from underflow", but it may be worth pointing out explicitly, as I have encountered this a few times in real-life use cases as the source of larger than expected errors, the root cause of which was only determined after careful range analysis. The issue occurs most frequently with single-precision (IEEE-754 `binary32`) data.

Comment: Do I understand it correctly: when doing arithmetics on a scaled data set, I get smaller absolute errors (0.01 instead of 100), but when scaling it back up, the errors will grow, as if they were performed with the original magnitude. This is due to the floating point numbers being evenly spaced in a relative, or logarithmic sense, so the represented real numbers are not "denser" in any interval, in the relative sense.

Comment: So probably the only time one should try optimize arithmetics, is when performing subtraction on large, but very similar numbers, and then it should not be scaling, but rather "shifting": subtracting the same number from each big number via non-arithmetic methods, so that the small result-number is not lost on the error of the absolute representation of those big numbers.

Comment: @ZoltanK.: Yes to your first comment. Regarding subtraction on large but similar numbers, there is no error when subtracting two numbers of the same sign such that the smaller is at least half the larger. The result of the floating-point subtraction is the exact mathematical result. Any errors in it are those already present in the two numbers. So no alternative technique can produce any better result at this point. It would be necessary to compute the numbers more precisely before reaching the subtraction.